# How to pause a command in discord.py while waiting for another command

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a minigame in discord where the bot allows us to bet on rolls and I need to make it so that it doesn't run until the other guy accepts the bet so I tried making a while loop to print not accepted until it the other person types !accept but it doesn't work and also for some reason it doesn't update the dictionary when a person wins so even after a deathroll a person's points still stays 1000 despite winning or losing

code:

```
@client.command()
async def deathroll(ctx,user:discord.User,bet=100):
    roller1 = ctx.author.id
    roller2 = user.id
    accepted=False
    if roller1 not in keys:
        await ctx.send("make an account first")
    if roller2 not in keys:
        await ctx.send("please give a user for roller2")
    while accepted!=True:
        print("not accepted")
        time.sleep(10)
    if roller2 in keys:
        roll=100
        while roll!=1:
            roll=random.randint(1,roll)
            await ctx.send("roller1,rolled:"+str(roll))
            if roll==1:
                await ctx.send("the winner is roller1")
                keys[roller1]=keys[roller1]-bet
                keys[roller2]=keys[roller2]+bet
                break
            roll=random.randint(1,roll)
            await ctx.send("roller2,rolled:"+str(roll))
            if roll == 1:
                await ctx.send("the winner is roller1")
                keys[roller2]=keys[roller2]-bet
                keys[roller1]=keys[roller1]+bet
                break

@client.command()
async def accept(ctx):
    accepted=True
```

Comment: I suspect the reason it doesn’t work is because I think it waits for the first command to finish before attempting to process the second one. This means the the while loop is blocking the entire program with a loop it cannot escape. You need to rewrite it to not block the program, I would suggest moving most of the logic to the accept function so it only tries to do the logic when it actually has all of the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't want to pause the command. You could do it, but it would stop the bot, and it wouldn't do any other task too, like in your case. Because of the repeating sleep() function, the bot cannot detect the !accept command. What you can do is that you setup an environment where you can save data about the bet (it can be a database, a txt file, anything) and you make a listener to the !accept command, where the program checks for the data saved before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `wait_for`, it waits for the given event and is async too

```py
@client.command()
async def deathroll(ctx,user:discord.User,bet=100):
    roller1 = ctx.author.id
    roller2 = user.id
    if roller1 not in keys:
        await ctx.send("make an account first")
    if roller2 not in keys:
        await ctx.send("please give a user for roller2")
    msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.author.id == user.id) # make sure that it only goes ahead when the mentioned user sends !accept
    while msg.content != "!accept":
        msg = await bot.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.author.id == user.id)
```

And I am assuming that `keys` is a dictionary defined outside the function, that's why you can not update it inside the function
There are 2 ways to solve this:

1. Add `global keys` in the function, globals are not the best
2. Make `keys` a bot variable

1st Way:

```py
@client.command()
async def deathroll(ctx,user:discord.User,bet=100):
    global keys
    ...
```

2nd Way:

```py
# wherever u define keys = {} do this instead
client.keys = {}
# then use client.keys[roller1] = client.keys[roller1]-bet
# basically replace `keys` with `client.keys`
```

Comment: i'm getting unsolved reference for bot in bot.wait_for, what should i  make the value of the bot variable be? or is it a module i need to import?

Comment: nevermind that question, how do i make the user unable to use the function until the other person has did !accept?

Comment: use which function? and yeah change bot to client my bad